# Interval missing and extrange behavior in frequency polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, statistics, histogram

I am preparing a material for students about Statistics and I have this generic-foo frequency polygon as an example, without the corresponding Histogram. I would like all intervals to be displayed in the `x axis`. If I write `intervals=true` key in `hist`, it shows all intervals but with a dot outside the plot quadrant, and when I change the key from `true` to `false`, it shows only some intervals but not the last one.
Also the plotted dots are not centered with respect to the intervals or the vertical lines.
How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=8,
        xmin=0, xmax=15,
        title={\color{blue} Polígono de Frecuencias},
        ybar interval,
        xticklabel={[\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick[}]
        ]
    \addplot[color=blue,forget plot,mark=*, hist={bins=5,data min=0,data max=15,handler/.style={sharp plot},intervals=false},shift={(axis direction cs:2,0) } ]
        table[row sep=\\,y index=0] 
        {data\\ 
        5\\ 14\\ 7\\ 1\\ 4\\ 9\\ 4\\ 5\\ 1\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 10\\ 9\\ 11\\ 2\\ 
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look here first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

Comment: @hpekristiansen Nice article at Wikipedia, but I could not find any reference of LaTeX in there or any possible solution to my issue. If your suggestion was in the direction of the missing histogram on my plot, I can deal with math accuracy later ;) . Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for just the reference without explanation. I never meant for the article to help you with LaTeX, but to show you how a real histogram is made. You need to follow the guidelines in book/other teaching material, but be aware that histograms are thought in many many different ways and often plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using an "empty" plot to get the desired tick description:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymin=0, ymax=8,
      xmin=0, xmax=15,
      title={\color{blue} Polígono de Frecuencias},
      ybar interval,
      xticklabel={[\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick[}],
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{hist={
      bins=5,
      data min=0,data max=15,
      handler/.style={sharp plot}
    }}
    % "empty" plot without shift and without intervals=false:
    \addplot[draw=none,forget plot,mark=none]table[row sep=\\,y index=0]{data\\0\\};

    \addplot[color=blue,forget plot,mark=*,
      hist={intervals=false},
      shift={(axis direction cs:1.5,0)}% <- changed
    ]table[row sep=\\,y index=0]{data\\ 
        5\\ 14\\ 7\\ 1\\ 4\\ 9\\ 4\\ 5\\ 1\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 10\\ 9\\ 11\\ 2\\ 
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Interesting trick of the "empty" plot. I did not know that `pgfplot` charges `TikZ`as well. Nice!